# override serve resource of user account in Liferay using hooks

Tags: liferay-6.2, liferay-hook

I am using Liferay 6.2. I made a hook to add some extra fields in User-My Acccount page. On key press of these fields, an ajax call needs to be invoked. I read [lifery service override](http://proliferay.com/liferay-service-hook-override-liferay-service/) and trying to follow the same approach: It works for updating user with new fields.

However, for ajax call, i need to override serve resource method somewhere. But i am not sure where exactly to call serve resource().

My approach is as follows:

In details.jsp

```
<portlet:resourceURL var ="userProfileURL"></portlet:resourceURL>
```

In js:
I call the ajax by using AUI io request: I pass mode as a parameter to check if it goes inside serveResource or not..

But before going to serve resource, it gives me an error saying userProfileURL is not defined. I have also included needed imports for it in jsp.

In userServiceImpl class that extends UserServiceWrapper, i tried to override serveResource:

```
public void serveResource(ResourceRequest resourceRequest, ResourceResponse  resourceResponse) throws PortletException {

         String mode = ParamUtil.getString(resourceRequest,"mode")
         if(mode.equals("getData")
         {
           // do needed processings & return data
         }

        else {
          //  super.serveResource(resourceRequest, resourceResponse); 
        }
```

But i get an error that says:

The method serveResource(ResourceRequest, ResourceResponse) is undefined for the type UserServiceWrapper

Is there any way to make ajax calls in hooks for user account page or am i oveririding on the wrong place?